# What do Potions have to do with hatching eggs?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I tap a Potion and swipe left, I see an incubator icon on right bottom. Can I use a potion on an egg?

Answer (score 11):

You cannot use potions on eggs.

The behavior you encounter is a result of how the Pokemon screen was built.  When you look at your Pokemon, you can swipe left to view your eggs.  This view is reused when you select a potion and are on the screen to select a Pokemon to use the item on.  As a result, you can swipe to view eggs on the "potion use" screen, but you cannot use a potion on an egg.

Answer (score -3):

I've heard a theory but I've yet to find anything on the matter yet, but locals in my town are going on about if you manage to get a 10k egg on 7k exactly then you can use a potion in the egg and it's supposed to boost its CP on hatching, working on a 10k atm slowly to see if there's any truth to it but will just says it's heresay for now

Comment: Were did you here this?

Comment: This is not accurate. You can never legitimately use a potion on an egg.

Comment: This is pure, straight up rumor mongering.  Please provide a source.

Comment: Yeah, and there's a Mew under my truck as well...